# IBAction inside of switch statement - Xcode

Tags: xcode, button, switch-statement, case

I have over 30 buttons and 30 images inside of a switch statement, 4 buttons showing at the same time.  I want to perform an IBAction depending on which button is pressed.  It's not allowing me to drag & drop it into the case inside my switch statement.  The buttons change depending on what image is showing.  For every image, there are 3 wrong buttons, and 1 correct button.  How can I check for which button is pressed, and add a resulting action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting it totally wrong. You should use switch statement to control look and feel of UI. Like controlling the 4 buttons to be shown by simply using `hide` property.

Each button should have an `IBAction` defined at class level. So, drag and drop connection from XIB/Storyboard to class and not inside switch statement. Depending on which button is currently shown, it action would be triggered.

**EDIT:** Post OP clarification:

Since you are trying to set different image on same button based on some condition and want to handle the `IBAction` based on the kind of image you set on it, you would need to set the `tag` on the button in your `switch` statement where you are setting images. `tag` takes an integer value so you can create `enum` for readability. Then when button is tapped and your `IBAction` is triggered, put another `switch` statement to check the value of `tag` and then take action accordingly.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'm still a novice.  Is there a way to check if a button is pressed?  if (btnExample isTouchInside) or anything similar?  The button action really depends on the image view that is being shown.  Some buttons appear for multiple images.  Its a guessing game based on the image shown.

Comment: When a button is pressed, first method that gets triggered is the linked `IBAction`.

Comment: For one image, the button is the correct answer, so I want my "Correct" label to show.  For another image, the same button is the wrong answer, and my "Wrong" label will show.    In the linked IBAction, can I add an if statement or check which image view is currently being shown?

Comment: Sorry I definitely screwed up my initial explanation.  I have 4 buttons total, but 30 different image views that are placed over each button, rather than having 30 separate buttons.  I was having re-sizing issues when putting background images on buttons so I have 4 invisible buttons with image views over them.

Comment: Are you trying to say that one button can have multiple images and based on the image you want to take the action? If so, then set the `tag` property on your `UIButton` wherever you are setting images on it. And then in your `IBAction` method, get the `tag` value and then based on the value take an action.

Comment: Yes! That's what I needed.  Thank you, been stuck on this all day.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer as well. If this helps, then please accept the answer for benefit of others.